# Invalid Signal processing library in Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, signals

I'm trying to compile a signal processing program in Linux (Ubuntu 12.01 LTS). Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
sigset_t ens1, ens2; 
int sig; 

int main(){
    /* Construction de l'ensemble ens1 = { SIGINT, SIGQUIT, SIGUSR1 }*/
    sigemptyset(&ens1); 
    sigaddset(&ens1, SIGINT); 
    sigaddset(&ens1, SIGQUIT); 
    sigaddset(&ens1, SIGUSR1); 
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &ens1, NULL);  /* Installation du masque ens1 */
    /* Envoi à lui-même de deux exemplaires de SIGINT et un de SIGUSR1 */
    raise(SIGINT); 
    kill(getpid(), SIGINT); 
    kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);
    /* Extraction des signaux pendants masqués */ 
    sigpending(&ens2);
    /* Impression de la liste des signaux pendants */
    printf("Signaux pendants: ");
    for(sig = 1; sig < NSIG; sig++){
        if(sigismember(&ens2, sig)) printf("%d ", sig); 
        }
    putchar('\n');
    sleep(15); 
    sigemptyset(&ens1); 
    printf("Déblocage de tous les signaux\n");
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &ens1, NULL); 
    printf("Fin du processus\n"); 
    exit(0);    
    }
```

The problem is that there are always errors as following:

```
gcc -o obj/signauxPendants.o -c src/Signal/signauxPendants.c -Iinclude -Wall -ansi
src/Signal/signauxPendants.c:18:1: error: unknown type name ‘sigset_t’

src/Signal/signauxPendants.c: In function ‘main’:
src/Signal/signauxPendants.c:23:2: warning: implicit declaration of function     ‘sigemptyset’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

src/Signal/signauxPendants.c:24:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sigaddset’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

src/Signal/signauxPendants.c:27:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sigprocmask’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

src/Signal/signauxPendants.c:27:14: error: ‘SIG_SETMASK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/Signal/signauxPendants.c:27:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

src/Signal/signauxPendants.c:30:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘kill’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

src/Signal/signauxPendants.c:33:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sigpending’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

src/Signal/signauxPendants.c:36:21: error: ‘NSIG’ undeclared (first use in this function)

src/Signal/signauxPendants.c:37:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sigismember’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

make: *** [obj/signauxPendants.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`signal.h` is a POSIX library, not a standard C library, remove the `-ansi` flag.

Comment: And add `#define _POSIX_SOURCE` to the top of the source or use gcc option `-D_POSIX_SOURCE`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have added #define _POSIX_SOURCE 1 in the top of my code. But there is one problem that they can not find NSIG symbol:                                                    error: ‘NSIG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/Signal/signauxPendants.c:37:21: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

Comment: is _POSIX_SOURCE in conflict with _BSD_SOURCE? is kill() not allowed for _BSD_SOURCE?